# Post request to my express server returns an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im just getting started with node and express and im trying to make a post request and push the results to an array for now. In the future i will be making these requests to a database, but for learning purposes i am doing this to an array now. Getting responses works, post requests gives me an error in postman.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express(); 
const port = 5000;
const arr = []; 

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/' , (req,res) => {
    arr.push(req.body);
    res.send(arr);
})


app.listen(port, () => {console.log(`listening on port ${port}`)});
```

Sadly the postman error doesnt tell me much.

The error :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot POST /</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

The request :

```
{
"app" : "Post"
}
```

Specifications of requeSt :

```
connection →keep-alive
content-length →140
content-security-policy →default-src 'none'
content-type →text/html; charset=utf-8
date →Fri, 23 Aug 2019 07:55:32 GMT
x-content-type-options →nosniff
x-powered-by →Express
```

Comment: Can you provide the error and maybe the request you're doing?

Comment: could you please post the error

Comment: @PimentoWeb — Why? It's not being reassigned anywhere.

Comment: @PimentoWeb — The value is not being changed. It is always a reference to the same array. (The array being mutated is by-the-by)

Comment: It only changes once, im pushing to it. I can push to an array even if its a constant. If it was changing multiple times it would be a let. @PimentoWeb

Comment: @Kevin.a — No. It doesn't matter how many times you mutate it.

Comment: The code works fine when I test it: https://i.imgur.com/jkhPcvD.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Actually you code is running in my machine, maybe you just forgot some postman configuration.

1. content-type: application/json
2. method: post
3. row data: {"data": "test"}

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this error could be attempting to use the '**get**' method with a '**post**' request in Postman. Therefore, you should ensure to select 'post' from the dropdown menu next to your API endpoint in Postman.